# Order of componentDidMount in React components hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, react-fiber

I have an React application that has the following structure:

component **A** is composed of **B** and **C**

When the component **B** calls it's `componentDidMount` method, **is this true that all component finished mounting?**

Or in other words **does React fire `componentDidMount` after all components in the tree were mounted?**

or e.g. Components **B** `componentDidMount` is called when component **A** mounted?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the documentation, the order of the lifecycle methods on first mount is as follows:

1. constructor()
2. componentWillMount()
3. render()
4. componentDidMount()

Let's say you have this component:

```
class A extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <B />
        <C />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When **A** is mounted, it will fire `componentDidMount()`. That will happen **after render**. Since B and C do not exist before A's `render()` is called, the completion of A's mounting requires that B and C finish their respective lifecycles. A's `componentDidMount()` will fire after B and C are mounted. A's `componentWillMount()` fires before A's `render()`, and therefore it also fires before B or C are mounted

**UPDATE**

As of React 16.3, `componentWillMount` starts the deprecation process, along with `componentWillUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps`. The above example will work fine in any 16.x release of react, but it will get deprecation warnings. There are new methods that take place of the deprecated ones, with their own lifecycle. More about them in the [component API docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html). Here is a [cheatsheet diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) for the new lifecycles

Comment: `componentDidMount` is not being deprecated.

Comment: @Skitterm oh yeah, it was a typo lol, I meant to write componentWillMount

Comment: Cheat sheet diagram attached to this answer is very useful for all the developers out there, no matter the level - beginner, average or advanced etc. Highly recommended. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Parent's `componentDidMount` fires **after** children's.

Similar issue: [In which order are parent-child components rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654982/in-which-order-are-parent-child-components-rendered)

Answer (score 0):

The React docs state:

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render()...

Each component will fire its own componentDidMount. A will its own, then B, then C.

So I guess the answer to your question is, no, not all components would have finished mounting, s they fire the life cycle method 'immediately before mounting'.

Comment: You used componentWillMount() description in answer to question about componentDidMount()... It's contradictive!