# In which order are React components re-rendered when global state is updated through hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Given a top-level `App` component that renders the following heirarchy:

```jsx
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

If both `Parent` and `Child` call the same hook to obtain some global state, and that state changes, will `Parent` or `Child` be re-rendered first?

Also, say they both use some variable, `user`, from global state, and that `Parent` only renders its `children` prop if `user` is not undefined. Will the `Child` prop ever be rendered with an `undefined` `user`?

Comment: For example if you rendering the child only when the user is present i infer that you mean something like this - { user && <ChildComponent } . If is it so then the `ChildComponent` will not be mounted when there is no user . So i don't think there is a possibility for it to render with `undefined`

Comment: You can check it by adding a `console.log` in render function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In which order are parent-child components rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654982/in-which-order-are-parent-child-components-rendered)

Comment: @Shyam Sort of. I mean in `Parent` I would have `{user && children}`. The `children` would in turn be `<Child />` in this case. I expected that `Child` should never even be rendered if `user` is `undefined`, but in my real production app it is, so I'm getting a `user undefined` error in `Child`. Note that both `Parent` and `Child` get `user` from a global hook -- it's not passed from `Parent` to `Child`.

Comment: @DennisVash I've tried that and I'm getting different logs locally and in production. Locally, `Parent` renders first, but in production, `Child` renders first, even though I'd expect it not to render at all, given the conditional I have in `Parent`.

Local console logs:
AuthLayout
CustomerDetailsForm
UPDATING USER VARIABLE
USER VARIABLE UPDATED
AuthLayout

Production console logs:
AuthLayout
CustomerDetailsForm
UPDATING USER VARIABLE
USER VARIABLE UPDATED
CustomerDetailsForm
TypeError: user is undefined in CustomerDetailsForm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet logging mount/unmount of parent and child. Child is only rendered when the state value is odd. Both components are accessing the same Context.

```js
const { useState, createContext, useContext, useEffect, useRef } = React;

const ViewContext = createContext();
const ActionsContext = createContext();

function MyContainer() {
  const [contextState, setContextState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <ViewContext.Provider value={contextState}>
      <ActionsContext.Provider value={setContextState}>
        <Incrementor />
        <Parent />
      </ActionsContext.Provider>
    </ViewContext.Provider>
  )
}

function Incrementor() {
  const setContextState = useContext(ActionsContext);

  const increment = () => {
    console.clear();
    setContextState(p => p + 1);
  }

  return <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>;
}

function Parent() {
  const contextState = useContext(ViewContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(contextState, ' - Parent Mounted');
    return () => console.log(contextState, ' - Parent Unmounted');
  }, [contextState]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is the parent: {contextState}</p>
      {contextState % 2
        ? <ConditionalChild />
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}

function ConditionalChild() {
  const contextState = useContext(ViewContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(contextState, ' -  Child Mounted');
    return () => console.log(contextState, ' -  Child Unmounted');
  }, [contextState]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is the child: {contextState}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyContainer />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```